# Display unicode character

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use spring boot 2 with thymeleaf 3.
I try to display an unicode character

```
<div th:utext="${specialTry ? &#x2611; : ''}"></div>
```

I get this error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "specialTry ? ☑
>   : ''"

I tried

```
th:utext="${sample.specialTry} ? '&#9745;' : ''"
```

only # is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that property `characterEncoding` should be explicitly set for `templateResolver` and `ThymeleafViewResolver`:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

JAVA annotation code :

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/UTF8-charset-problem-td3608879.html

Comment: should be done by spring boot, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html we can see it's already utf8

Comment: use java annotation approach resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is single quotation marks around the unicode part

```
<div th:utext="${specialTry ? '&#x2611;' : ''}"></div>
```